# Optimizing the number and placement of valves in a pipe network to meet requirements

Tags: optimization

If you have ‘n’ components connected via piping, and ‘m’ modes of operations that dictate how fluid flows between the components in each mode, is there an algorithmic way to optimize how many multi-port valves with ‘x’ ports are required to satisfy all mode requirements such that the total number of valves is reduced? Example below:[example of three valves (valves are in color, pumps are grey)in a pipe network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfKPF.png)